# Do all applications have a command line interface?

Tags: bash, shell

I've been learning shell script on my Mac recently. Take an application like Atlassian's SourceTree as an example. My understanding is that it's just a GUI for git commands, which can be executed through command line. Pressing a button just triggers a corresponding git command, which is effectively run through the command line behind the scenes. If that is the case, do all applications that have a GUI function this way? Are all applications essentially just running their commands through the machine's shell script? And if so, are the underlying commands that are being used publicly available, offering an API of sorts for any application?

Comment: No. Why do you assume that?

Comment: Some do, some don't.

Comment: nit: invoking an external program to perform work is not necessarily running that command "through the machine's shell script".  The shell provides a convenient mechanism for invoking programs, and if a program is most commonly invoked through a shell it is often referred to as a "command line" tool.  A program can invoke a shell as a wrapper to call the external tool, but that step is certainly not necessary.

Comment: Well, I'm asking. My understanding is that shell script is the main interface to the kernel of a machine. So applications that are running on the machine have to eventually boil down to a series of shell commands, even if they are built at a much higher level, right?

Comment: The main interface to the kernel is a C API called _system calls_. Shells just provide a more abstract interface to that API.

Comment: 'Main interface' meaning there are others, or no?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more complex than that.

Many applications only have a GUI (e.g., Safari), many others only have a CLI (e.g., `find`).

When a GUI app and a CLI app perform the same function, they may communicate with each other or they may not:

- As you point out a GUI application can run a CLI command behind the scene (with `system()` or `popen()` for instance)
- An alternative is that both applications use the same underlying library
- Or no code is shared at all (think of `ls` vs. Finder on Mac)
- Finally on Mac some GUI apps can be controlled with Applescript language, which is available through `osascript` command. In other words, you can control iTunes with a bash script.

Comment: Thank you - helpful explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely, not all applications behave that way. In fact, from my experience, I'd say that there are few applications that follow that. Most applications perform their own operations relying directly on the OS platform and functionalities, instead of executing shell commands which, in addition, are hard (and most of the time impossible) to port between OSs.